# Selenium WebDriver. Python. How to assert Chinese text in the tag?

Tags: python, selenium, localization, selenium-webdriver, non-ascii-characters

I am getting "ASCII" errors trying use str.decode(), unicode.encode() and other functions. Can't understand how properly use it.

HTML code which I am trying to assest:

```
<div class="head">
   <h1 id="localizationHeading">本地化</h1>
</div>
```

My assert script:

```
assert driver.find_element_by_id("localizationHeading").text == str.decode("本地化")
```

I also tried to use this script:

```
assert "本地化" in driver.find_element_by_id("localizationHeading").text
```

P.S. In the top of my code is `# coding: utf-8` .

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "day2.py", line 53, in <module>
    assert driver.find_element_by_id("localizationHeading").text == str.decode("
µ£¼σ£░σîû")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

And these:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "day2.py", line 52, in <module>
    assert "µ£¼σ£░σîû" in driver.find_element_by_id("localizationHeading").text
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

`assert driver.find_element_by_id("localizationHeading").text == "本地化".decode().encode('utf-8')` also doesn't work - the same issue.

Comment: Please post the "different errors."

Comment: Done. Actually it's always one error, sorry.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Replacing `.decode().encode('utf-8')` with `.decode('utf-8')`:

```
assert driver.find_element_by_id("localizationHeading").text == "本地化".decode('utf-8')
```